# IdentityServer4 - combining MVC and SPA - avoid extra round trip

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-mvc, identityserver4, openid-connect, implicit-flow

I have a website which combines ASP.NET Core MVC and angular based SPA which I am trying to secure using IdentityServer4. The login flow currently looks like:

1. User clicks the login button on the homepage (www.example.com, MVC
   based)
2. User is redirected to a login page (login.example.com, MVC based) and logs in
3. <strike>User is redirected to www.example.com/app where site detects it doesn't have a cookie for the user so it redirects the user to the login.example.com/connect/authorize endpoint</strike>
4. User is redirected back to the site with the id_token to www.example.com/signin-oidc which drops the cookie
5. User is then finally redirected to the www.example.com/app which should show the SPA

The problem is then when this is finally done, the SPA needs the access token so it can call the APIs. I tried using angular-auth-oidc-client library, the trouble is that this waits for the whole angular app to load app only to find out it doesn't have the access token and do yet another redirect to the login.example.com/connect/authorize endpoint to get the token.

Is there a simpler way do this? I.e. redirect the user to the app with the access token at step 5? Or choose a completely different approach to the identity?

Comment: So you have the access token in your server side code and you need a way to provide it to your client side code? Could you write it into a (session) cookie that your client code could then read and use?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, after step 2 user should be logging in and then step 4 why 3, not sounds right. This scenario should be handled by hybrid flow and when step 4 happens client app should have id token and access token. you should now have Controllers where you can access "Access Token". you can create a base class that returns httpclient with headers set.

And all you calls from angular app should go through these controllers, which will call your server apis.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, the step 3 is incorrect, it goes directly to step 4. Regarding the others, what do you mean by client app? The MVC uses cookies as auth and in the step 4 creates a cookie with an id token. Where does the angular app get the access token?
Btw. the APIs are a bunch of completely separate sites and I would like to call them from angular app directly, not through another server.

Comment: ClientApp means client of your Identity Server, your angular app. what Grant Type your client app using? Hybrid or Implicit

Comment: Currently I am using the implicit flow as I found it in various sources as tge recommended flow for SPAs. From what I understand, the only. difference would be getting the id token and the access token in one roundtrip, but on the side of the MVC. How should I securely pass it to the angular app?

Comment: well if you are using Implicit flow then you can use [oidc-client library](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js). As with implicit flow access tokens would be passed to the browser and this library has all other useful methods to check if user is authenticated etc. but you said that you used it, didn't quite understand what the issue is

Comment: I am using it, the trouble is the double roundtrip to the authorize endpoint, once to be redirected to signin-oidc, then the angular SPA is loaded, it finds out it doesn't have the token so it redirects to the authorize endpoint again, this time for the access token.

Comment: something is not right then how you have setup your app, please go through the [samples](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/release/Clients/src/JsOidc) i myself had setup one in past and we never had this issue, once user logged in and back on the SPA it can access tokens right away